# Converting .swf to .fla

Tags: flash, converters, flash-cs5, fla

First of all I'm really confused that should I ask this on SO. If not can you guys provide me an alternative where I can ask this?

I have a `.swf` file and I need to convert it to `.fla`so that I can get my `actionscript` code back and start developing again.

The file was developed by me Using `Adobe Flash CS 5.5` on `Windows 8` and I exported it as `swf`.

Then I stored that `swf` file on my `USB stick`(My regular backup). But unfortunately I forgot to store `.fla`.

And Now My HDD is crashed, and can't be repaired.

So is there any way that I can get `.fla` file from `.swf`?

I've seen [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Decompile-Swf-Files-and-Convert-Swf-to-Fla), and came to know that it is possible.

Is there any Free / Open source s/w to do it? Thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 0):

You can try decompile your swf. It won't be a clean code or anything like that, but might save you some time.

Back in the day I had a problem with a project I was able to recover it using this: http://www.ave-imperator.com/

Now, use it only with your own code, please don't try to decompile someone's code, it's a terrible thing to do.

Good luck.